# Atom feed cannot be received

Tags: java, android, exception, atom-feed

I am using my usual code to receive a feed in XML and store it as a String, but getting an "unknownhostexception".

link: http://android-tv-app.com/Hls8zUWPqa9C2U/feed/atom

code:

```
String answer = null;
HttpUriRequest request = null;
HttpResponse resp = null;
InputStream is = null;
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(10000));
try {

    request = new HttpGet(url);
    request.setHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");

    resp = client.execute(request);
    if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
    { 
        error = 3;
        return null;

    }
    HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();

    return convertStreamToString(is);

} catch (Exception e)
{
    error = 3;
    return null;
}
```

Update 1:

This could be my problem, Can someone explain this:

Including in XHTML
The following tag should be placed into the head of an XHTML document to provide a link to an ATOM Feed.

from

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29#Atom_compared_to_RSS_2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually means you are not connected to the internet.
Check your internet connection in the phone's/emulator's browser.

Plainly said, the best thing to do in such cases is to handle the exception gracefully and inform the user he/she is not connected to the internet.

Comment: I am connected to the internet, definitely. My browser is working.

Comment: Then maybe you lack the INTERNET permission in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Thankyou tacone, have been programming android for over 6 months and still do something stupid like that. I m mad at myself.

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing, now I am getting half of the result in stream, errors like invalid xml, end tag not received are showing up.